# When do we start mocking? Using Gmock framework

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am new to Gmock and mocking stuff in general.
Let's assume we have the following code

```
void FirstClass::FirstFunction()
{
    int x;
    SecondFunction(x);
}

void SecondClass::SecondFunction(int value)
{
    ThirdFunction();
}

void ThirdClass::ThirdFunction()
{
//do something
}
```

We want to test FirstFunction.
Should we mock SecondFunction, or go one step further and only mock ThirdFunction?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Your code is not valid. 2) There are no hard-and-fast rules; it depends on what you want to achieve with your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The code was just intended to prove the point I was making, I didn't intend to have something valid. I just wanted to know at what level it is recommended to start mocking functions.

Comment: The question is too generic. That depends on what exactly do you need to test.